# How to embed customized List on MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

Hi I'm trying to place customized listview on top of the mapFragment (I'm using GoogleMaps api V2). This mapFragment is within a Fragment of a ActionBarTab. I've looked into tileOverlay and groundOverlay, but they are all about placing images(as per my understanding) on the map. Is there a way to inflate a ListView on the mapFragment.
This is my fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_regional_analysis" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"                   
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is fragment class

`

```
public class RegionalFragment extends Fragment 
  {

static final LatLng UK = new LatLng(53.4167, 3.0000);
static final LatLng LONDON = new LatLng(51.5171, 0.1062);
static final LatLng Brimingham = new LatLng(52.4800, 1.9100);
private MapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;
ProgressBar progressBar;
int progress = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container,
            container, false);
    mapFragment = new MapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            map = mapFragment.getMap();

            if (map != null) {
                 setupMap();
            }
        }
    };
    // fragment added dynamically
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.mapView, mapFragment).commit();
    return v;
}`
```

Logcat errors:

```
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be        cast to android.view.ViewGroup
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-16 09:38:40.300: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put it into your layout file?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="AS_YOU_WANT_IT" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And inflate this in your fragment?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that my mapfragment is within a actionbar tab fragment. I tried putting listview there but my app crashed.

Comment: could you post that solution's code and logcat result? or do you know the reason of the crash?

Comment: There's no such errors in logcat, but the emulator screen starts blinking rapidly. Dont know why.
But isnt there a way to inflate listview on the map??

Comment: I don't understand "on the map". It should overlap the map? In that case the solution would be puting listview and mapfragment into a FrameLayout instead of a LinearLayout

Comment: "on the map" as in overlap the map, such that the map is visible through the listview.
i'm doing nested fragments here, i cant put fragment into the framelayout.

Comment: Well, I would put mapfragment and listview into a framelaout, and set the listview transparent.

Comment: I get an runtime error if i do that
` 04-16 09:11:52.002: E/AndroidRuntime(823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 09:11:52.002: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
04-16 09:11:52.002: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)`

Comment: could you please post your xml and your code? (and please indicate, which line is the one throwing the exception)

Comment: If you want to use mapFragment (or supportMapFragment), modify your xml: from <View .../> to <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

And you can get your map like mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap(); instead of new MapFragment()

Comment: Nested fragments cant be done like that. Please read http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: All right, but the reason of the crash is still that in the xml there is <View.../> as the mapFragment instead of <fragment.../>, this is what's causing the classCastException. For adding a List to the mapFragment you don't need two fragments, simply Put a ListView in the same layout as MapFragment is in.